# Display Buttons above the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I a have made a registration form in which i have two buttons.Now what i want is that when the keyboard is displayed the two buttons which are at the bottom should be displayed above the keyboard and not hidden under the keyboard.To achieve this the code i wrote didn't gave me any success.

Xml Code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:hint="@string/firstname"
                    android:id="@+id/et_first_name" />


                <EditText
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:hint="@string/lastname"
                    android:id="@+id/et_last_name" />

                <Button
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:text="@string/country"
                    android:id="@+id/bt_country" />


                <Button
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:text="@string/gender"
                    android:id="@+id/bt_gender" />

                <EditText
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:hint="@string/mobileno"
                    android:id="@+id/et_mobile_no" />

                <EditText
                    style="@style/EditText"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:id="@+id/et_email" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:id="@+id/bt_reg_cancel"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:id="@+id/bt_reg_save"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please do help

Comment: why don't you use scroll view ?

Comment: Put your Buttons inside ScrollView and try......

Comment: I  want to keep the buttons positions fix

Comment: use this parm in you activity declartion in manifiest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android Manifest, give the property `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. This will resize your layout when keyboard shows.

So if something is on the bottom, it will show above the keyboard once it shows

**"Please can u show me the code with relative layout, it would be very helpfull??? –  user3917131 7 mins ago "**

**Solution :-**

1. ) Either put your bottom layout in the scrollview itself. Then even if the keyboard is showed, you can scroll it.

2.) Weight Approach :-
ScrollView -> 0.7
RelativeLayout -> 0.3 -> In it write your bottom layout and give the property align parent bottom true.
In this approach, your scrollview will take only 0.7 of screen as per weight guidelines and the rest by your bottom layout

3.) remove scrollview, instead make it linearlayout. Make Top Parent Relative Layout and give the property align parent bottom true to your bottom layout and the layout above property to your linearlayout

Comment: because you whole layout is in a scrollview, that is why it wont work. Because you can scroll, it will not resize. Remove scrollview and it will work

Comment: The whole layout isnt in the scroll view

Comment: At compile time it is not known that your layout is at the bottom. It is just coming in bottom because your scrollview has many childs in it. If your have only one child in scrollview, then your bottom layout will not come at the bottom.Either make the main parent relativelayout and set align parent  bottom true

Comment: I have modified my answer and provided three approaches but not the full code

Answer (score 0):

You should set leyout_weight of ScrollView to 1 for example. And set leyout_height of LinearLayout to "wrap_content". And that would be nice to set layout_height of ScrollView to 0dp, so LinearLayout can manage it`s heigth.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:id="@+id/bt_reg_cancel"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:id="@+id/bt_reg_save"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

That should do the trick.